Prove $\int_{0}^{x} \frac{dt}{(t^2+a^2)^2} = \frac{x}{2a^2(x^2+a^2)} + \frac{1}{2a^3} \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$
Show that :
$\int_{0}^{x} \frac{dt}{(t^2+a^2)^2} = \frac{x}{2a^2(x^2+a^2)} + \frac{1}{2a^3} \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+C$
by
differentiating
$\int_{0}^{x} \frac{dt}{t^2 + a^2} = \frac{1}{a} \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$ under the integral sign .
What I tried was :
$\int_{0}^{x} \frac{dt}{t^2 + a^2} = \frac{1}{a} \tan^{-1} \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)=F(a)$
then differentiating it inside the integral with respect to $a$ as the parameter keeping $x$ constant . It provided me with solution :
$$ \frac{d(F(a))}{da} = -\frac{x(\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{a}))}{a^2} $$
I then integrated with respect to $a$ giving me a result of :
$F(a)=-x\left(\frac{\ln\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+1\right)}{2x} - \frac{\tan^{-1}(x/a)}{a}\right) + c$
where $c$ is the constant of integration that comes out to be $0$.
This gives me :
$ F(a) = -x\left(\frac{\ln\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+1\right)}{2x} - \frac{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)}{a}\right) $
At this point I am stuck with no idea how to proceed.
I apologize if the question lacks context.

You can't have $x$ as a bound of an integral, and as the dummy variable in the integral itself. The problem is ill-stated.

Not to come off as rude/inconsiderate , I acknowledge the solution you have provided , which I wandered on too for quite some time . But this is a undergrad problem mentioned by a professor in the exact same manner. On searching about it I tried to go with the most basic approach of differentiating inside the integral sign and came to such a conclusion where I was left stuck. :)

Then the professor in question is in error. I don't really care who posed it, the problem is still ill-posed.

The point of the exercise is to note$$\frac{d}{da}\int_0^x\frac{1}{t^2+a^2}dt=\int_0^x\frac{\partial} {\partial a}\frac{1}{t^2+a^2}dt.$$

That is how is proceeded with the problem.

In a way, you proceeded in the reversed order. Given that
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a}\frac{1}{x^2+a^2} = -\frac{2a}{(t^2+a^2)^2},
$$
you should have gone as follows :
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^x\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{(t^2+a^2)^2}
   &= -\frac{1}{2a}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a} \int_0^x\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t^2+a^2} \\
   &= -\frac{1}{2a}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}a} \left(\frac{1}{a}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right) \\
   &= -\frac{1}{2a}\left(-\frac{1}{a^2}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right) + \frac{1}{a}\frac{1}{1+(x/a)^2}\frac{-x}{a^2}\right) \\
   &= \frac{1}{2a^3}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right) + \frac{1}{2a^2}\frac{x}{x^2+a^2}
\end{align}
$$

Firstly, I believe you meant $\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\text{d}t}{(t^2 + a^2)^2}$. As others have pointed out, you cannot use $x$ as an integration variable and a bound at the same time. Please fix the question.
Now, for the problem itself.
Note:
\begin{align} \frac{d}{da} F(a) \neq -\frac{x \text{ arctan}(\frac{x}{a})}{a^2} \end{align}
Recompute the derivative of the right-hand-side using the product rule. Most likely, you forgot that $\text{tan}^{-1} (x/a)$ is also a function of $a$.
Then, for the left-hand-side, differentiate under the integral sign:
\begin{align} \frac{d}{da}F(a) = \int_{0}^{x} \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \frac{1}{(t^2 + a^2)^2} \text{d}t 
\end{align}
The second differentiation should immediately lead you to the answer. The definite integral you should get from doing the second differentiation is just a factor depending on $a$ off of $\int_{0}^{x} \frac{1}{(t^2 + a^2)^2} \text dt$. Divide that factor to both sides of the equation and you may write Q.E.D.
